# Difference between “getting rich” and “becoming rich”

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between *becoming rich* and *getting rich*?

If there is, what would it be?

Comment: "Getting rich" is more informal language and "becoming rich" is more formal language.

Comment: Either can refer to the process or the accomplishment.

Comment: "getting rich" is used in negative phrases like "get-rich-quick scheme", but I don't think it's necessarily disreputable in itself. I can't see any difference as to source of money or anything like that.